# arduino compilation error

Tags: compiling, raspberrypi

I am using arduino (2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4) on ubuntu mate(Raspberry pi 3 B model), while sketch it showing following error, could you any one tell how to solve this problem.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3797)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5086)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4272)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:5097)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using an overly complex Regular Expression, possibly unconditionally recursive.  You have used up all of Java's stack (the 1st line tells you that).

Answer (score 0):

Regex engines can only do so much work, and I imagine generally they're RAM bound. If you're trying to match against a particularly large string or using a particular kind of regex - see for example [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7510006/2152081)

> Unfortunately, Java's builtin regex support has problems with regexes containing repetitive alternative paths (that is, (A|B)*). This is compiled into a recursive call, which results in a StackOverflow error when used on a very large string.
>
> A possible solution is to rewrite your regex to not use a repititive alternative, but if your goal is to tokenize a string on semicolons, you don't need a complex regex at all really, just use String.split() with a simple ";" as the argument.